# awk/sed filename add to pattern match

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have multiple html files to combine into a single html file, but I need to modify the hyperlinks to avoid having same hyperlinks when I combine them.

file name: chapter1.html, chapter1.html etc.

I want to find this tag

```
 <a href="#4">
```

and replace it with file name (chapter1.html), output must be like this (want to exclude the extension of the file name)

```
<a href="#chapter14">
```

how can I do this with either awk or sed? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this with sed:

```
> file='chapter1.html'
> f="${file%.*}"
> echo "$f"
chapter1
> sed 's/\(href="#\)\([^#]*\)"/\1'"$f"'\2"/' "$file"
```

**Multiple file solution:**

```
for file in *.html; do
    f="${file%.*}"
    sed -i.bak 's/\(href="#\)\([^#]*\)"/\1'"$f"'\2"/' "$file"
done
```

Comment: I can't get this, it doesn't include file name chapter1.html. I'm looking for something like; sed 's/href="#/$filename/g' chapter1.html

Comment: great, does the job very well. Is $f means the file name without extension? I just wrote sed 's/\(href="#\)\([^#]*\)"/\1'"$f"'\2"/' file.txt and it works. But your script has assigning variable etc, where you ran those scripts? sorry but I'm a noob :(

Comment: Yes `$f` is filename without extension. Make sure you run it in BASH shell.

Comment: it doesn't really work well, it requires to assign variables and I can't do this for multiple files in the same time. I want to try it in flow something like this and I'll do this for multiple files; sed 's/\(href="#\)\([^#]*\)"/\1'"$f"'\2"/' file.txt

Comment: check update for editing multiple files. This also supports inline editing.

Comment: Thanks I responded and followed you back on Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

```
for File in *.html
 do
   sed "s|\(<a href=\"#\)\([[:digit:]]\{1,}"\)|\1${File%.*}\2|g" ${File} >> FinalFile.html
 done
```